# Cannot mount Windows 8 partition disk on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ubuntu-12.10

I cannot mount Windows 8 partition disk on Ubuntu 12.10.

My Windows 8 is installed on "C" partition, and I have another "D" partition.

I can easily mount "D" partition, see files and make changes on them.
Actually I also have a problem with this: when I copy a file from ubuntu to "D", I cannot see this file on Windows 8.

My main problem is when I try to mount "C" partition I get this:

> Unable to mount 121 GB Volume
>   Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/furkan/06DEC78FDEC77589: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda3" "/media/furkan/06DEC78FDEC77589"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
>   Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
>   The NTFS partition is hibernated. Please resume and shutdown Windows
>   properly, or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option, or
>   mount the volume read-write with the 'remove_hiberfile' mount option.
>   For example type on the command line:

```
        mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda3 /media/furkan/06DEC78FDEC77589
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 8 uses *hybrid shutdown* by default. It means that it will just close most applications and hibernate to start faster next time. And hibernated Windows partitions can't be mounted.

There are few solutions:

- [disable hybrid shutdown](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) completely
- shutdown Windows from command line (or simply by typing on the Start screen, or with a shortcut to this command): `shutdown /s /t 0`
- reboot to Ubuntu - reboot is always using complete shutdown

Comment: Or mount the disk in read-only mode.