# "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount" but fast startup is disabled on Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, fedora, linux-mint, fstab

I'm trying to mount a Windows 10 partition on Fedora 23, with `read-write` permitions (but the same problem occurs on Linux Mint 17.3 and Ubuntu 15.10), but everytime I get this message:

```
$ sudo mount /media/windows
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operação não permitida
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

This is how my `/etc/fstab` file looks like:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Fri Dec  4 18:50:21 2015
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=b9fe99a1-3a93-4cca-8fa1-0ab62fb8d134 /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=6E0C67260C66E913   /media/windows          ntfs    default,rwx      0 0
UUID=2E0A29CB533416A0   /media/finger           ntfs    default,rwx     0 0
```

Now, I know there are a lot of questions around Superuser, Ask Ubuntu and other SE variants about the same subject, **but there's a difference here**:

I have already disabled the **fast startup** "feature" from Windows 10, avoiding the *partial hibernation*, have properly shut it down and restarted, but the partition is still locked in hibernation. This problem persists through every Linux distribution, they can't mount the Windows partition.

What should I do to fix this problem?

**EDIT:**

I want to be able to put Windows 10 in hibernation mode **when I want to**. I don't want to completely disable hibernation. I was always able to do so on Windows 7, so what changed on Windows 10 that the partition is *always* in hibernation lock after a **full shutdown without fast startup**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dual boot ubuntu with windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/807490/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-8)

Comment: @Ramhound no as I wrote before it was marked: "I have already disabled the fast startup feature from Windows 10". The problem is different.

Comment: You are welcome to disagree with my suggestion it is a duplicate, does not mean, it isn't one.  [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/563325/cannot-mount-windows-8-partition-disk-on-ubuntu-12-10?rq=1) is another one.  [here](http://superuser.com/questions/957081/how-to-enable-disable-fast-startup-in-windows-10?rq=1) is a specific Windows 10 duplicate.  [here](http://superuser.com/questions/902137/keeping-fast-startup-for-windows-8-in-a-win-linux-dual-booting-environment?rq=1) is another one. [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/579831/mount-hibernated-windows-partition?rq=1) is an alternative

Comment: @Ramhound The question you linked as this being duplicated of if not a duplicate. It is about something else. The other two alternatives are also about something else. The 3rd one is actually helpful. The last one also doesn't answer the question as I know how to disable the fast startup - As I said in the question, it already was disabled.

Comment: Hibernation isn't disabled though

Answer (score 3):

Disable hibernate by `powercfg -hibernate off`
For details, see http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html

Comment: I didn't want to turn off hibernation mode completely as I find it useful when the computer is running out of battery. This might be the only solution though.

Comment: The warning message speaks for it self.  "Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.".  You need to make sure neither of those conditions are true to avoid this warning message..  The reason the warning is not an "and" statement is because only certain versions of Windows supports "fast restarting"

Comment: Fast Startup in Windows cannot work without hibernation.

Comment: @BrunoFinger just as a temporary test, does disabling hibernation work? Maybe windows 10 is just ultra-stubborn and always "dirties" it's filesystem when hibernation is even enabled, though not used?

Comment: Disabling hibernation works in my Windows 10.

Comment: @Xen2050 I just tried disabling hibernation completely with the command `powercfg -hibernate off` as Administrator and then restarted the computer. Yes it works. But I would really like to find a way to have hibernation enabled. I am ok with the fact that if Windows 10 is hibernated I won't be able to write to its partition, but while it isn't I should be able to, right? I believe there should be some setting somewhere that will solve this issue...

Comment: At least it works with no hibernate, maybe it's a windows 10 builtin "feature" to just "fake hibernate"  it's filesystem even when it's not really hibernated. Odd

Answer (score 0):

[itimees](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/412999/itimees) gave me the [hint I needed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587300/87996):

Hold the `Shift` key down while selecting `Shutdown` from the Windows Login power menu option.

---

*#Ignorable_Background*

My task was to reset a lost password on a Windows computer.  I could boot to Linux from a USB, but the Windows, NTFS volume would only mount in read-only as version 10 of Windows usually hibernates on shutdown.  This prevented me from clearing the user's password in the read-only SAM file.

Since I didn't have the password, I could not use the other answers here to clear the hibernation file or turn off hibernation upon shutdown, ...

Another post recommended `sudo ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdXN /path/to/mount`, run from the Linux terminal, but this did not work since the Windows Volume could only be mounted in read-only mode, no file changes could be made.

itimees' hint (above) let me know that I could hold the `Shift` key down on the Windows computer when I `Shutdown` from the power menu option on the Windows Login screen.  This then performed the needed full (no hibernation) shutdown.  The Windows Volume was then able to mount in read‑write mode from the Linux boot and the user's password was then able to be cleared.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).